# AngularJS : e2e tests with Karma Scenario Test Runner using cached source?

Tags: testing, angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to set up some AngularJS e2e tests with Karma Scenario Test Runner. I did some modifications to the source files, but Karma doesn't seem to use these latest versions when testing.

In the source files, I added ids to some elements. Karma still couldn't find them, so I added a pause in the e2e test, so that I can mark and "Inspect elements" (using Chrome) on the current page in the test runner. The source code seems correct, except the latest changes are missing, i e, the ids aren't there. So what's happening here? Do I need to explicitly tell Karma the files have been updated somehow?

Comment: I found a solution a few minutes after posting, but decided to leave the question here for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this issue by forcing angularjs to clear the application cache:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome developer tools settings, check "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)".

Obviously, this is a much more general issue than Angular's e2e test runner, but I decided to leave it here for now, in case somebody else has the same question.